# I want to get started with modulation recorded audio

Tags: audio-recording, audio-interfaces, modulation, app, applications

In there an app (preferably Android) that can take a audio recording (music, voice, etc.) and change the frequency to above or below human hearing (infrasonic and ultrasonic)  and vice versa. I want to explore the possibilities of what I can do with it. I played with a few frequency generators but it's limited.

Comment: Thanks. I have a frequency generator (Android) on one phone and started playing it on below 15 mhz with another and saw how it on another phone using Spectrum Wave (iphone). Unrelatedly, I even toyed with the idea of communication through modem sounds. I've been able to record sounds to below hearing level (or so I believe) it shows up on spectrograph app. I don't have much experience yet but I want to learn any suggestions on what I can do to start with playing with sound to cause physical vibrations has been a interesting thing to play with.

Answer (score 1):

TL:DR You will not be able to do this in any meaningful way on a phone.

I'm not sure what you mean by 'modulation recorded audio' [unless you're referring to PCM, pulse-code modulation] but you can change frequencies most simply by changing sampling rate for playback - in effect speed it up or slow it down.

Alternatively, there are algorithms that can change pitch independantly of speed. Even the simplistic Audacity has a [pitch-shift module](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/change_pitch.html).

Your main problems in doing this are going to be

1. Pitch-shifting by extreme amounts distorts the signal quite badly, introducing unwanted artefacts.
2. You probably lack the equipment to actually play back any audio outside the normal human hearing spectrum… not that you could hear it if it did. You will certainly never achieve this kind of playback on a phone; not even on a home hifi or HTPC. It requires expensive, specialist equipment.

Apart from playback, you also lack the equipment to record anything outside the human hearing spectrum. See [How can I record frequencies from 0.1 to 20 Hz?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/38504/how-can-i-record-frequencies-from-0-1-to-20-hz) for the low end. You will hit comparable issues at the high end.